# Needing VueJS Getter to only return all values of the last JSON property as an array

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, vuex

I am using a Django REST back-end to ship API data to a VueJS front-end.
I am trying to place daily counts in a ChartJS graph.

```
import { HorizontalBar } from '../BaseCharts'

export default {
  extends: HorizontalBar,
  data() {
    return{
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    /* Need to write the API call for chart data here. */
    this.$store.dispatch("DailyCountAction")

this.renderChart({
  labels: [this.$store.state.DailyCount],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Existing Patients',
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
      'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
      'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
  ],
  borderWidth: 1,
      data: [4,8,2,]
    },
```

You can see in the "label" field I have a getter which returns the data:

```
 {
        "Check_In_Count": "7",
        "Average_Time_Spent": "3",
        "Average_Wait_Time": "2",
        "Cancelations": "0",
        "New_Patient_Count": "4",
        "Existing_Patient_Count": "3",
        "Current_Cycle_Date": "2062019"
    },
    {
        "Check_In_Count": "4",
        "Average_Time_Spent": "8",
        "Average_Wait_Time": "6",
        "Cancelations": "0",
        "New_Patient_Count": "1",
        "Existing_Patient_Count": "3",
        "Current_Cycle_Date": "2072019"
    },
    {
        "Check_In_Count": "7",
        "Average_Time_Spent": "3",
        "Average_Wait_Time": "9",
        "Cancelations": "0",
        "New_Patient_Count": "0",
        "Existing_Patient_Count": "7",
        "Current_Cycle_Date": "2082019"
    },
    {
        "Check_In_Count": "8",
        "Average_Time_Spent": "8",
        "Average_Wait_Time": "1",
        "Cancelations": "0",
        "New_Patient_Count": "4",
        "Existing_Patient_Count": "4",
        "Current_Cycle_Date": "2092019"
    },
```

I am needing to only return all the Current_Cycle_Date values into an array that goes into the "labels" field. I am very confused on how I could go about this.

In the end the label field should look like:
labels: ['2092019', '2082019', '2072019', '2062019']

I've seen examples of using the MAP in getters. Nothing has worked so far. Could this be accomplished using some logic in a Method?

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to return only `Current_Cycle_Date` from the backend add some code to the question. If you want to do it in the frontend I think @muka.gergely has posted the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try returning it as an array:

```
const data = [{
        "Check_In_Count": "7",
        "Average_Time_Spent": "3",
        "Average_Wait_Time": "2",
        "Cancelations": "0",
        "New_Patient_Count": "4",
        "Existing_Patient_Count": "3",
        "Current_Cycle_Date": "2062019"
    },
    {
        "Check_In_Count": "4",
        "Average_Time_Spent": "8",
        "Average_Wait_Time": "6",
        "Cancelations": "0",
        "New_Patient_Count": "1",
        "Existing_Patient_Count": "3",
        "Current_Cycle_Date": "2072019"
    },
    {
        "Check_In_Count": "7",
        "Average_Time_Spent": "3",
        "Average_Wait_Time": "9",
        "Cancelations": "0",
        "New_Patient_Count": "0",
        "Existing_Patient_Count": "7",
        "Current_Cycle_Date": "2082019"
    },
    {
        "Check_In_Count": "8",
        "Average_Time_Spent": "8",
        "Average_Wait_Time": "1",
        "Cancelations": "0",
        "New_Patient_Count": "4",
        "Existing_Patient_Count": "4",
        "Current_Cycle_Date": "2092019"
    }]


var ccd = data.map( i => i.Current_Cycle_Date )

console.log( ccd )
```

Comment: My data comes through an Action Axios Call I do not have it hardcoded in the front-end, but this seems to be the best possible solution to working it out. Thank you very much!